# Could AltBeacon library be used to wake up my app as soon as a beacon comes in range, even on Android 8+?

Tags: android, altbeacon

I wish to code an app that a user installs and then forgets about it. When his/her android smartphone detects a beacon on a street (I don't care about distance, RSSI power,...), it launches my app. Is there a way to react as soon a the beacon is found without draining the battery or having scans occur every 15 min or so in Android 8+? What happens if the user moves along a street where are located 2+ beacons? Can he/she detect the other ones too as soon as he/she approaches them?
Can AltBeacon library suit my needs?

I rapidly read the AltBeacon documentation, just to find if my project could be realistic, but I don't still have a clear vision of the BLE limitations on Android.

Perhaps it's better if I spend a couple more words on what I am trying to code. I wish to place a beacon in 30-40 shops of different kind (clothes, food, services,...) in a relatively small area. When a user, with my app installed (but not running) on his android smartphone, passes by one of those shops, my app shoud wake itself up and notify him that in shop XY there is a particular offer.

So, before I dive into learning Java and Android Studio (I usually code in Delphi), I want to be sure that:

1) Could my app detect the beacon X in shop A and, 2 minutes later, when the user cross the street and gets closer to shop B, detect its beacon Y too? Will the 15 minutes limitation keep me from detecting beacon Y (and all the others)?

2) I don't care about distances between the user and the shops: if my app "sees" beacon X it's sufficient to trigger a notification of an offer. Will this requirement drain the user's phone battery?

Regards,
Filippo

Thank you very much,
Filippo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Android Beacon Library does exactly what you describe out of the box.  You can test it with the [reference app](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference).

First detections in the background typically come in [0-5 seconds](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/detection_times.html), even on Android 8+.

The default behavior on Android 8+ *is* to do a brief full BLE scan for a few seconds every 15 minutes, which is on top of a constant hardware-filter-backed low power scan.  Tests show this uses very little battery and users typically do not notice the difference of it being active.

Due to background running limitations on Android 8+, there is a limit to detecting multiple distinct beacons in the background in quick succession.  Generally speaking, the library out-of-the-box will not detect a new beacon detection more frequently than once in 15 minutes.  There are ways to configure the library to support detecting more, but they require launching a foreground service for 15 minutes after a first beacon detection to detect the additional beacons until the next 15 minute cycle starts.

The above limitations apply both to the Android Beacon Library and any similar SDK using Android BLE scanning.  See [here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8) for a description of why this is so.

Be aware, however, that some Chinese Android OEMs build proprietary power-saving features into their phones that can prevent any long-term background work from functioning unless you can somehow get your app whitelisted by the Chinese OEM.  See [here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2019/04/30/the-rise-of-the-nasty-forks) for more info.

Comment: Thank you David. What do you mean exactly when you say "which is on top of a constant hardware-filter-backed low power scan"? Please, note that I edited my post and I added some more info: could you answer my new questions?

Thank you again for your patience and help.

Comment: The constant hardware-filter-backed low power scan generally gives you really fast beacon detections.  But it doesn't always work, because (a) some low quality phones don't have this feature and (b) it only works if there aren't any beacons around.  The 15 minute full scan is done as a backup for cases where the phones have no hardware filter capability or where there are already beacons around.

Comment: As a beginner Java/Android programmer, you'l probably need to use the library in its out-of-the box configuration.  That means that if you detect a beacon at store A, the library won't guarantee a quick detection at store B unless 15 minutes passes where no beacons are seen.